# Amazon S3 Upload NoHttpResponseException

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have the next code for uploading files to an Amazon S3:

```
AmazonS3Client client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, 
            new ClientConfiguration().withMaxConnections(100)
                                  .withConnectionTimeout(120 * 1000)
                                  .withMaxErrorRetry(15));
TransferManager tm = new TransferManager(client);
TransferManagerConfiguration configuration = new TransferManagerConfiguration();
configuration.setMultipartUploadThreshold(MULTIPART_THRESHOLD);
tm.setConfiguration(configuration);

Upload upload = tm.upload(bucket, key, file);

try {
    upload.waitForCompletion();
} catch(InterruptedException ex) {
    logger.error(ex.getMessage());
} finally {
    tm.shutdownNow(false);
}
```

It works, but some uploads(1GB) produce the next log message:

```
 INFO AmazonHttpClient:Unable to execute HTTP request: bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com failed to respond
 org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com failed to respond
```

I have tried to create TransferManager without AmazonS3Client, but it doesn't help.

Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The log message is telling you that there was a transient error sending data to S3. You've configured `.withMaxErrorRetry(15)`, so the AmazonS3Client is transparently retrying the request that failed and the overall upload is succeeding.

There isn't necessarily anything to fix here - sometimes packets get lost on the network, especially if you're trying to push through a lot of packets at once. Waiting a little while and retrying is usually the right way to deal with this, and that's what's already happening.

If you wanted, you could try turning down the `MaxConnections` setting to limit how many chunks of the file will be uploaded at a time - there's probably a sweet spot where you're still getting reasonable throughput, but not overloading the network.